# Swift: Unpacking a tuple into mutable and immutable variables simultaneously

Tags: swift, coding-style, tuples, mutability, destructuring

I have a Swift function which returns a tuple of two values.  The first value is meant to usually, but not always, be used as an "updated" version of a piece of mutable state in the caller (I know I could also use `inout` for this instead of a tuple, but that makes it more annoying to keep the old state while preserving the new one).  The second value is a generally immutable return value produced by the function, which is not intended to override any existing mutable state.

Conceptually, the usage looks like this:

```
var state = // initialize
(state, retval1) = process(state)
(state, retval2) = process(state)
(state, retval3) = process(state)
```

The problem here, obviously, is that `retval1`, `retval2`, and `retval3` are never declared, and the compiler gets angry.

`state` must be a `var` and must not be redeclared, so I can't write

```
let (state, retval) = process(state)
```

However, `retval` is never modified and should be declared with `let` as a matter of best practices and good coding style.

I was hoping the following syntax might work, but it doesn't:

```
(state, let retval) = process(state)
```

How should I go about unpacking / destructuring this tuple?

Answer (score 4):

I don’t believe there’s a syntax for binding with `let` and `var` simultaneously.

Interestingly, you can do it in a `switch`:

```
let pair = (1,2)
switch pair {
case (var a, let b):
    ++a
default:
    break
}
```

But `(var a, let b) = pair` (or similar variants) don’t seem to be possible.